# How to set element.scrollLeft upon focus in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to do something like this on an input element in AngularJS:

`function onFocus() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('myInput');
  elem.scrollLeft = elem.scrollWidth;
}`

Like that the cursor is always at the end when it has focus.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: Huh, I only asked it here and nowhere else on StackOverflow.

Comment: you asked [how to place the cursor at the end of a text input on focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663764/angularjs-how-to-place-caret-to-end-upon-focus) 11 hours ago, then 1 hour ago asked this question, essentially asking the same thing, just listing a bit of code for `onFocus()`.  There is no substantial difference between these two questions.

Comment: the one question i posted on github?